# Transliterator transliterate Rules

Tags: php, unicode, transliteration

I use this function to transliterate Cyrillic words into Latin:

```
$string = transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC;', $name);
```

However, I get single-letter matches instead of composite ones.
That is, I get the word "Финиш" after processing "Finis" and it should be "Finish"

For example (in parentheses is written what should be according to the standard)

```
ш -> s (sh)
щ -> s (shch)
ч -> c (ch)
.... and other
```

For example full right table:

```
а-a б-b в-v г-g д-d е-e ё-e ж-zh з-z и-i й-i к-k л-l м-m н-n о-o п-p р-r
с-s т-t у-u ф-f х-kh ц-ts ч-ch ш-sh щ-shch ы-y ъ-ie э-e ю-iu я-ia
```

As I understand it, you need to configure it somewhere in the rules, but I can't Figure out how to do it in the documentation.

Or perhaps there is some other option?

Comment: even the manual has a couple of comments with the single-letter transliteration of Russian. Doesn't make any sense :-(

Comment: @WalterTross So you think it's easier to write your own function?

Comment: If I were you I would read thoroughly the documentation and also wait for an answer here. If both fail in a couple of days I would probably go with `str_replace()`.

Comment: @WalterTross [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) could be better than `str_replace()` for this?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to write rules for the particular cases:

```
$str = 'а-a б-b в-v г-g д-d е-e ё-e ж-zh з-z и-i й-i к-k л-l м-m н-n о-o п-p р-r
с-s т-t у-u ф-f х-kh ц-ts ч-ch ш-sh щ-shch ы-y ъ-ie э-e ю-iu я-ia    Финиш';

$rules = <<<'RULES'
:: NFC ;
ё > e; ж > zh; й > i; х > kh; ц > ts; ч > ch; ш > sh; щ > shch; ъ > ie;
э > e; ю > iu; я > ia;
:: Cyrillic-Latin ;
RULES;

$tls = Transliterator::createFromRules($rules);

echo $tls->transliterate($str), PHP_EOL;
```

Note that the "particular rules" have to be before the general rule (`Cyrillic-Latin`).

Comment: Yes, this is it. I have updated my [blog post](https://www.jasom.net/php-prepare-sanitize-transliterate-convert-change-user-string-input-for-filename-or-url-address/) dedicated the the issue, thank you. NOTE: Official documentation about [Transliterator::createFromRules](https://www.php.net/manual/en/transliterator.createfromrules.php) lacks the rules code sample. `This function is currently not documented; only its argument list is available.` (but where is the argument list?)

Comment: @JasomDotnet: you can find a documentation [here](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/transforms/general/rules.html).